# Are HSV values stored as VSH in numpy array?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, colors

since RGB is stored as BGR ,does the same happens in the case of HSV ?

I am making a project where i take input from webcam and convert it to HSV colour, to track object of a specific colour.

Comment: I think we need more context.  When is RGB stored as BGR?

Comment: BGR simply reflects the ordering of the wavelengths from shortest to longest commonly used in remote sensing.  Which is correct? Depends on your discipline, useage is the controlling factor.

Comment: No, the order is hsv. Pay attention to the data ranges, h  [0,179], s and v [0,255]

Comment: @Aditya: Please can you describe your issue further. Are you loading a normal image and converting it to HSV or you have saved an image in HSV format to disk using OpenCv.

Comment: @saurabheights i am converting normal image into HSV format

Comment: @Adityasrivastava : See my answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's HSV mode.

Read the below code and its run on a sample image.

```
int main()
{
    // Load your Red colored image
    cv::Mat frame = imread("test.png");

    // Split each channel
    cv::Mat rgbChannels[3];
    cv::split(frame, rgbChannels);
    cv::imshow("RGB", frame);

    // Check value of your Red, Blue and Green Channel
    double minVal, maxVal;
    // Note: Blue is first channel
    cv::minMaxLoc(rgbChannels[0], &minVal, &maxVal);
    std::cout << "Blue: Min = " << minVal << ", Max = " << maxVal << std::endl;
    cv::minMaxLoc(rgbChannels[1], &minVal, &maxVal);
    std::cout << "Green: Min = " << minVal << ", Max = " << maxVal << std::endl;
    cv::minMaxLoc(rgbChannels[2], &minVal, &maxVal);
    std::cout << "Red: Min = " << minVal << ", Max = " << maxVal << std::endl;

    std::cout << "*******************************" << std::endl;

    cv::Mat hsv;
    cv::Mat hsvChannels[3];
    // Convert BGR image to HSV. Dont use CV_RGB2HSV.
    cv::cvtColor(frame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    // Split each channel
    cv::split(hsv, hsvChannels);

    // **Display HSV image: Note: When displaying opencv does not display image as Red image**
    // This is because imshow will just take first channel which is hue and treat it as Blue, second channel as 
    // Green, and last channel as Red.
    cv::imshow("HSV", hsv);
    cv::minMaxLoc(hsvChannels[0], &minVal, &maxVal);
    std::cout << "Hue: Min = " << minVal << ", Max = " << maxVal << std::endl;
    cv::minMaxLoc(hsvChannels[1], &minVal, &maxVal);
    std::cout << "Saturation: Min = " << minVal << ", Max = " << maxVal << std::endl;
    cv::minMaxLoc(hsvChannels[2], &minVal, &maxVal);
    std::cout << "Value: Min = " << minVal << ", Max = " << maxVal << std::endl;
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Red Image]

**Output:-**

```
Blue: Min = 36, Max = 36
Green: Min = 28, Max = 28
Red: Min = 237, Max = 237
*******************************
Hue: Min = 179, Max = 179
Saturation: Min = 225, Max = 225
Value: Min = 237, Max = 237
```

**Output Explanation**
 Using this [tool](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm), the RGB value (237, 28, 36) maps to HSV (358, 88.2, 92.9). Since, HUE ranges from 0 to 359, the value crosses 1-byte bound of allowing only 256 values. The HUE is divided by 2 to range from [0,179] in opencv to use less memory. The hue value 358 divided by 2 maps to 179 which is the first channel. Also, saturation and value are just normalized to scale 0-255. Thus as you can see saturation maps to second and value maps to third channel.

Answer (score 0):

No. But there is function which is apply to RGB values. And it is stored as HSV format in numpy array.
To see this Go to Opencv Documentation [Opencv Documentation Color Conversion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html).